# JavaFX - horizontal marquee text

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, marquee

I am trying to achieve effect similar to [marquee](http://www.htmlmarquee.com/) - line of long (in my case) text which is moved in horizontal axis. I managed to get it work, but I can't call it satisfactory.

My `Controller` class looks as below:

```
@FXML
private Text newsFeedText;

(...)
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    TranslateTransition transition = TranslateTransitionBuilder.create()
            .duration(new Duration(7500))
            .node(newsFeedText)
            .interpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR)
            .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE)
            .build();   

    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();

    transition.setFromX(width);
    transition.setToX(-width);
    transition.play();
}
```

`newsFeedText` is binded to some text source which is dynamically updated, so it contains various amount of text.

My code has at least two drawbacks:

- Transition goes from `-width` to `+width`; `width` is monitor's resolution width

There will be moments when text will not be visible at all if window is not full-screened.
If text will be longer and `newsFeedText` width will be greater than monitor's resolution width then transition will disappear "in half" (still being on a screen).

- Currently `Duration` is not dependent on a width of `newsFeedText`.

Now, it's nothing worng, but if transition's `fromX` and `toX` were be dynamically calculated then it will result in various speeds of marquee.

How to get rid of these drawbacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed it to work, any recalculations can happen only after transition is stopped so we cannot set its `cycleCount` to `Timeline.INDEFINITE`. My requirement was that I could change text inside component so there are fxml wirings:

```
@FXML
private Text node; // text to marquee

@FXML
private Pane parentPane; // pane on which text is placed
```

The code which works is:

```
transition = TranslateTransitionBuilder.create()
        .duration(new Duration(10))
        .node(node)
        .interpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR)
        .cycleCount(1)
        .build();

transition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        rerunAnimation();
    }
});

rerunAnimation();
```

where `rerunAnimation()` is:

```
private void rerunAnimation() {
    transition.stop();
    // if needed set different text on "node"
    recalculateTransition();
    transition.playFromStart();
}
```

and `recalculateTransition()` is:

```
private void recalculateTransition() {
    transition.setToX(node.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX() * -1 - 100);
    transition.setFromX(parentPane.widthProperty().get() + 100);

    double distance = parentPane.widthProperty().get() + 2 * node.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX();
    transition.setDuration(new Duration(distance / SPEED_FACTOR));
}
```

Comment: Consider donating a marquee control to [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).

Comment: It works within all window width, but how if i need ticker inside control? I can't hide text particulary

Comment: @jewelsea I think that my "workaround" solution is too inefficient, but in a spare time I will certainly improve it and donate solution.

Comment: Also consider to put a Rectangle shape under the marquee Text object with the size larger than visible screen area to achieve smooth animation. Your Text shape must run over this rectangle all the path. And don't forget to set shape's caching.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by listening to your scene's `widthProperty`. You can either access this via `newsFeedText.getScene().widthProperty()` or get a reference from your main class and expose it from there or pass it to a method or constructor to access within your class that declares `newsFeedText`.

The benefit of this approach is that now your logic is dependent upon the width of your scene (a dynamic dependency) rather than the width of your monitor (a static dependency). Note that I have not tested this approach but at the moment see no reason  (perhaps naively) it shouldn't work.

As for your duration dependency, you can solve that by performing some sort of calculation based on the length of the text in `newsFeedText`. Something like `Duration.seconds(newsFeedText.get Text().length()/denominator)` where `denominator` is some value you specify (such as 7500, as in your code). This will make your duration dynamically computed based on the length of your text.

If you want to operate with the width of `newsFeedText` itself, rather than the length of its text, then simply replace `newsFeedText.getText().length()` with `newsFeedText.getWidth()`. Ensure you perform this computation after `newsFeedText` has been laid out so a call to get its width returns the actual width. You can also replace the call with any of `getPrefWidth()`, `getMinWidth()`, or `getMaxWidth()`.

Comment: It's where another problem rises, if you bind `TranslateTransition#toX`, call `TranslateTransition#play` and change the size of the window, transition will not change its `toX` until it is stopped and played again. In my case, code is called in `Initializable#initialize` method so the size of my scene is equal to zero at that moment

Comment: Use a `ChangeListener` registered on the width property. In there, set your values of your transition to the new values reported by the `ChangeListener`.