# Create scrolling text when text is too long

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, horizontal-scrolling

I have a dynamically built string that is sometimes too long, but still needs to be displayed fully to the user. I would much rather have the text scroll than creating a tooltip for it.

I have creating a label with this:

```
Label text = new Label("hello there i hope this text is long enough to take up space");
TranslateTransition tran = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(75000));
tran.setNode(text);
tran.setByX(-400);
tran.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
tran.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
// add the text
tran.play();
```

One, when I do this, if the text is `"this is really long"` and it's shortened to `"this is really..."` then when the label scrolls, the text remains `"this is really..."`. Another thing is this scrolls the label away, changing the x position of the element. Is there a way to just change the text will a scroll instance?

Also, is there a way to programatically determine if a given text is going to be too large for a specified area?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062430/javafx-horizontal-marquee-text) on creating a marquee controller.

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest method could be "marquee":

- http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee
- http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/marquee-html-element/

But it´s nonstandard: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/

A better method is CSS3: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/